# Is there a way to validate /etc/crontab’s format?

Tags: cron

I prefer to stick scheduled tasks in /etc/crontab so I can see at a glance what's scheduled to run, regardless of which user the task runs as.

The only gotcha is that the format isn't validated on save, unlike crontab -e -- so a stray character can quietly break the entire cron.

Is there a way to validate the /etc/crontab format before/after save?

Comment: If, like me, you came here looking for a simple (non-scriptable) way to tell you whether you'd got your cron entry right, you might be interested in http://www.cronchecker.net — it's an online validator for cron entries with human-friendly output.

Answer (score 47):

The only reliable way I found is to check the log.

`cron` checks `/etc/crontab` every minute, and logs a message indicating that it has reloaded it, or that it found an error.

So after editing, run this:

```
sleep 60; grep crontab /var/log/syslog | tail
```

Or, to not wait a full minute, but only until the next minute + 5 seconds:

```
sleep $(( 60 - $(date +%S) + 5 )) && grep cron /var/log/syslog | tail
```

Example output with an error:

```
Jan  9 19:10:57 r530a cron[107258]: Error: bad minute; while reading /etc/crontab
Jan  9 19:10:57 r530a cron[107258]: (*system*) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)
```

Good output:

```
Jan  9 19:19:01 r530a cron[107258]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
```

That's on Debian 8. On other systems, cron might log to a different file.

(I thought I could avoid hunting for the right log file by using systemd's `journalctl -u cron`, but that didn't show me these log entries, and actually seems to have stopped logging cron events 2 days ago for some reason)

Comment: Tested on FreeBSD 10.3. Works like a charm, just replace log path with /var/log/cron

Comment: Path to cron log in Rocky 9 is also /var/log/cron like FreeBSD 10.3.

Comment: There's no /var/log/syslog in my docker container

Answer (score 16):

Another more recent solution is the python script [chkcrontab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chkcrontab)

Comment: It doesn't check users' cronjobs yet

Comment: It told me that cron wouldn't run the file because it contains dots in the file name. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

[Wicked cool shell scripts](https://www.nostarch.com/wcss2/) has a shell script that validates crontab files.

You can get the zip archive containing the script [here](https://www.nostarch.com/download/WickedCoolShellScripts2e_resources_updated.zip)

The script is called **verifycron**

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore as of 11 jan 2017.

Comment: Someone fixed the link. In the zip-file it is located in "wicked_cool_shell_scripts_2e-master/6/48-verifycron". Use it with `./48-verifycron /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` to verify your user root crontab-file.

Answer (score 6):

I found this cool solution here: https://crontab.guru

It doesn't just validate the crontab, it tells you explicitly what and when the crontab will run, and highlights where errors are.

Answer (score 0):

Tailing the logs is the best solution I feel, as pointed out by @mivk in their answer.

`journalctl` is a good option too:

```
vedant@zebronics:~$ journalctl -u cron.service 
... <hit shift+G to goto last line>
Nov 03 10:33:01 zebronics cron[627]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
```

(Hit `shift+G` to go the latest line in journal)

Answer (score 0):

This has worked the best for me:

```
systemctl restart cron; journalctl -u cron --lines 10
```

Forcing the restart ensures that `cron` checks the syntax immediately, instead of waiting 60 seconds. If there are any errors, `journalctl` will show them.

Answer (score -1):

run `crontab -T path/to/crontab`

If you want to automatically do it before/after, you can write your own `visudo` style wrapper, such as

```
$EDITOR /etc/crontab
crontab -T /etc/crontab
```

Personally, since breaking the crontab is not as bad as breaking sudoers, I think it's fine to just print the message, but you could also  everything to a tempfile if you wanted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What OS is this valid for? My crontab command on Ubuntu does not have the -T flag at all

Comment: This is from "cronie" cron by Paul Vixie and Colin Dean. I am on Arch Linux. Info is from my man page.